# How to iterate nested struct in Go?

Tags: html, json, xml, api, go

I get erro message that "Range Cann't iterate over....list of data in Curl brackets"

I have the following struct

```
type FamilyMembers struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"familyMember" json:"familyMember"`
    Text         string   `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
    ResponseCode string   `xml:"responseCode"`
    Family     []struct {
        Text    string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
        Parents []struct {
            Text   string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
            Parent []struct {
                Text      string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
                FirstName string `xml:"firstName" json:"firstName"`
                MidleName string `xml:"midleName" json:"midleName"`
                SurName   string `xml:"surName" json:"surName"`
                Gender    string `xml:"gender" json:"gender"`
                DoB       string `xml:"doB" json:"doB"`
            } `xml:"parent" json:"parent"`
        } `xml:"parents" json:"parents"`

        Children []struct {
            Text  string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
            Child []struct {
                Text      string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
                FirstName string `xml:"firstName" json:"firstName"`
                MidleName string `xml:"midleName" json:"midleName"`
                SurName   string `xml:"surName" json:"surName"`
                Gender    string `xml:"gender" json:"gender"`
                DoB       string `xml:"doB" json:"doB"`
            } `xml:"child" json:"child"`
        } `xml:"children" json:"children"`

    } `xml:"family" json:"family"`
}
```

I want to list all data in one table but i always get error message that excuting "body" ay <.FamilyMembers >: range cann't iterat over......then it dislay all data in console window with that error as following

```
{{ if .FamilyMembers }}
    <table >
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Names</th>
           <th>Gender</th>
           <th>Born</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          {{ range .FamilyMembers }}
          <tr>
             <td>{{ .FirstName }} {{ .MidleName }} {{ .SurName }}</td>
             <td>{{ .Gender }}</td>
             <td>{{ .DoB }}</td>
          </tr>
          {{ end }}
       </tbody>
   </table>
 {{ else }}
    <h5 class="mt-3 text-center">No family details</h5>
{{ end }}
```

i can not get the expected results as i i tried to iterate

Comment: Using `range .FamilyMembers` where `FamilyMembers` is a struct causes the problem. Nether Go nor its template package support iteration over a struct's fields. You need to explicitly specify the **slice** fields you want to iterate over, like the `Family []struct` field, and inside it the `Parents []struct` and `Children []struct` fields. And you need to use the correct selector expressions when referencing those fields. Neither Go nor its template library will do it for you, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: You should you take the [Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1).

Comment: @mkopriva technically your advice is correct, but why the nitpicking in the last sentence?

Comment: @mkopriva than you for you contribution

Comment: No problem @NewdevEloperj. And if my comments came off as unnecessarily nitpicky I apologize, I wish you only good fortune on your Go journey.

Comment: @mkopriva i taken it in positive way so you don't worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got what i wanted to display by doing the following on iteration,

```
 {{ range $i, $a := .FamilyMembers.Family}}
  {{ range $j, $b := .Parents }}
       {{ range $k, $c := .Parent }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ .FirstName }} {{ .MidleName }} {{ .SurName }}</td>
                <td>{{ .Gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ .DoB }}</td>
              </tr>
           {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
        {{ range $j, $b := .Children }}
             {{ range $k, $c := .Child }}
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ .FirstName }} {{ .MidleName }} {{ .SurName }}</td>
                      <td>{{ .Gender }}</td>
                      <td>{{ .DoB }}</td>
                  </tr>
            {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
```

By doing that help to display data in all inner structs (nested structs)